# How to make cards appear on screen - Unity, C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a card game, and I'm having trouble with making cards appear on screen. Does anyone know how I can make them appear at the bottom of the screen with a gap between each card? The idea being something similar to Solitaire, and when you click a card, it moves above the other cards with all the stats displayed.

My player manager code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class s_PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour {

public bool isAi;
public s_DeckSetUp deckManager;
public List<Card> PlayerDeck = new List<Card>();
public List<Card> PlayerHand = new List<Card>();
public List<Card> PlayerGrave = new List<Card>();
public Card selectedCard;
private int totalHandCount = 5;
public int cardCount = 0;

void Start(){
    deckManager = GameObject.Find("Deck Manager").GetComponent<s_DeckSetUp>();
}

public void StartDeck(){
    for(int a = 0; a < deckManager.DeckAllCards.Count; a++){
        int b = Random.Range(0, deckManager.DeckAllCards.Count);
        PlayerDeck.Add(deckManager.DeckAllCards[b]);
    }
    DrawHand();
    EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.SetActive(false);
}

public void DrawHand(){
    for(cardCount = 0; cardCount < totalHandCount; cardCount++){
        int b = Random.Range(0, PlayerDeck.Count);
        PlayerHand.Add(PlayerDeck[b]);
        PlayerDeck.RemoveAt(b);
    }
}

public void CardDraw(){
    if(cardCount < totalHandCount){
        int b = Random.Range(0, PlayerDeck.Count);
        PlayerHand.Add(PlayerDeck[b]);
        PlayerDeck.RemoveAt(b);
        cardCount++;
    } 
 }
}
```

It handles creating the players deck, and drawing the first 5 cards. The CardDraw function is triggered by clicking a UI button. Can anyone possibly tell me how to have the cards appear on screen? I have the card art in the project files. Any help is greatly appreciated. I also posted this on the Unity forums: 
https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/making-cards-appear-on-screen.475335/

Comment: Are you struggling with the positioning of the cards base on the number of cards in the hand? Or more with how to get the sprite on screen? Or perhaps how to get the correct location for the card in world space?

Comment: I am struggling with all of it. I have no idea how to even start.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain to you how to get a single card to show at the bottom of the screen first.

The hardest part for you would probably be to calculate the world position of where you have to put your sprites (I assume you have sprites for your cards).

How I would go about this is to calculate the SCREEN position of where you want your cards, since your requirement is for them to be at the bottom of the screen.

You can use Screen.width to get the width of your screen. The height does not matter because we want to place the cards at Zero height which is the bottom edge of the screen.

The bottom center of the screen in screen space will be

`Vector2 botCenterScreenSpace = new Vector2(Screen.width/2, 0)`

You can get the bottom center of the screen in world space by using the following code:

```
var botCenterWorldSpace = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(botCenterScreenSpace.x, botCenterScreenSpace.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
```

The quickest way to see if this works is to setup your sprites. By default the sprite anchor should be exactly in the center of the card which is fine for now.

Create a prefab for your card. To make things easier to test we will setup a `CardDealerUi` script.

```
public class CardDealerUi : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject cardPrefab;

    private Vector2 botCenterScreenSpace;
    private Vector3 botCenterWorldSpace;

    void Start()
    {
        this.botCenterScreenSpace = new Vector2(Screen.width/2, 0);
        this.botCenterWorldSpace = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(botCenterScreenSpace.x, botCenterScreenSpace.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
    }

    void OnCardDrawn(Card cardDrawn)
    {
        GameObject newCardUi = GameObject.Instantiate(this.cardPrefab, this.botCenterWorldSpace, Quaternion.indentity);

        // Here you can swap sprites for your cards or so.
    }
}
```

To test this just do some basic keyboard input and call OnCardDrawn with any Card object.

In this example you had only 1 prefab. For you to realize your game you may want to setup a prefab for every type of card or you would want to have 1 prefab and swap out the sprites where I commented above.

So far you should have one card on screen. Now the problem is where to put the second and third and forth card and so on. This will require some math to get it how you want.

I will not go into detail but you would most likely have 2 constants in your dealer script. `float CardWidth` and `float CardGap`.

When you deal 5 cards you would probably want to calculate the total width of all the cards including the gaps. That is `var totalWidth = numCards * CardWidth + (numCards - 1) * CardGap`. Then the offset from the botCenterWorldSpace would become something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cardsToDeal.Length; i++)
{
    var cardPosition = botCenterWorldSpace - new Vector3(totalWidth + (totalWidth/cardsToDeal.Length*i) + CardWidth/2, 0, 0);
}
```

Just in case you wondered where this code belongs, you will have a new function in you CardDealerUi. Something like this:

```
public class CardDealerUi : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject cardPrefab;

    private Vector2 botCenterScreenSpace;
    private Vector3 botCenterWorldSpace;

    void Start()
    {
        this.botCenterScreenSpace = new Vector2(Screen.width/2, 0);
        this.botCenterWorldSpace = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(botCenterScreenSpace.x, botCenterScreenSpace.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
    }

    void OnCardsDrawn(List<Card> cardsDrawn)
    {
         for(int i = 0; i < cardsDrawn.Length; i++)
        {
            var cardPosition = this.botCenterWorldSpace - new Vector3(totalWidth + (totalWidth/cardsDrawn.Length*i) + CardWidth/2, 0, 0);

            GameObject newCardUi = GameObject.Instantiate(this.cardPrefab, cardPosition , Quaternion.indentity);
        }


        // Here you can swap sprites for your cards or so.
    }
}
```

I hope this can get you on the right track.

From here you will need separate research on animating the cards and moving them on mouse over.

Comment: That being said, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question